# Composition series exists for every finite group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm struggling with a bit of this proof that every finite group $G$ admits a composition series, that is a series of containments

$$ \{1\} = H_0 \subset H_1 \subset \ldots \subset H_k = G $$

where $H_i \triangleleft H_{i+1}$ and the quotient $H_{i+1} / H_i$ is a simple group.

The proof is by induction. The base case where $|G| = 1$ is trivial, $G$ is its own composition series. Now if $|G| > 1$ and $G$ is simple then our series is just $ \{1\} \subset G$.

So assume there is some normal subgroup $H$ of $G$, between the trivial subgroup and $G$ itself.

By hypothesis this admits a composition series itself,

$$\{1\} = H_0 \subset H_1 \ldots \subset H_k = H. $$

Now $H$ is normal, so we can construct the quotient group $G / H$. Apparently this admits a composition series,

$$H / H = \{1_{G/H} \} := N_0 \subset \ldots \subset N_l = G / H,$$

that is a series of quotients of subgroups of $G$ each of which contains $H$.

My question is, how do I know that this second composition series exists? It doesn't seem to follow from the induction hypothesis, but rather is an analogous case. Would I perform a similar induction, with the base case being $G = H$ and so $G/H$ is trivial, and next $H \subset G / H$ is my first non-trivial case?

Also, the proof proceeds by using the third isomorphism theorem to show that

$$H_{k+i+1} / H_{k+1} \cong (H_{k+i+1}/H) / (H_{k+1}/H) = N_{i+1} / N_i.$$

It asks me to consider "the preimage of $N_i = H_{k+i}/H$ in $G$." I can only assume that means the preimage under the projection $\pi_i : H_{k+i} \rightarrow H_{k+i} / H$?

Comment: But the proof is by induction on $|G|$, so it does follow from the induction hypothesis because $|G/H| < |G|$.

Comment: I can see that must be true by Lagrange's theorem. I'm still a bit confused.
So I can see that it's very similar to induction on $|G|$, because I can either say $G / H$ is simple, or I have some finite chain of subgroups $H \subset \ldots \subset N_j \subset G/H$.  But why do I get to say that $(G/H )/ N_j$ is simple? Even if induction is on the length of composition series, that chain I just mentioned could be longer then the composition series for $H$, could it not?

Comment: Never mind! Induction is on the order of $G$,  and although the chain might be longer that doesn't matter because the order of $G/H$ must be less than $G$ for non-trivial cases, and so these admit a composition series.
I suppose where I went wrong, is that bigger groups may have shorter composition series, and I sort of assumed that bigger group means bigger series. Is that right?
Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Any group of prime order has a composition series of length $1$, so arbitrarily large groups (in fact even inifnite groups) can have composition series of length $1$. But a group with a composition series of length $n$ must have order at least $2^n$.